# In a standard two-column document, i'd like a long figure to take roughly 1.5 columns wide, but not all they way across two columns

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I'm aware that i can use `\begin{figure}` for a full 1 column placement, `\begin{figure*}` to span both columns, and `\begin{wrapfigure}` for a partial column figure placement.

But I need my figure to be roughly 1.5 columns and would like to wrap text on one side.

Can I do this (easily)?

Comment: Put your graphic file in a `\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering...}`.

Comment: @Bernard How will that help?

Comment: @cfr:  the graphic file  will be 1.5 column wide, and centred  w.r.t. text width.  Or did I misunderstand the requirement?

Comment: @Bernard But how will that handle the wrapping?

Comment: @cfr: I didn't understand wrapping was required. Do you think so?

Comment: @Bernard I assumed so. Otherwise, you are just looking at a `figure*`, aren't you? And then just `\centering` is enough - you don't need a `\parbox`. I took it that the point of the question was that there's a way to get a double-column figure (`figure*`), a way to get a full single-column one (`figure`) and a way to get a partial-column one (`wrapfigure`), but how do you get a one-and-a-bit-column one? And I assume the issue is that there's no `wrapfigure*`.

Comment: It can be done, but it requires manually aligning a gap in one column with a wrapfigure in another.

Comment: @cfr @bernard, yes I did mean that tex would still be wrapped. I edited the question to clarify. So it seems the `\parbox` won't help. 

@john kormylo, can you provide more details?

Comment: @JohnKormylo ^^ OP: note that you can only ping one person at a time.

Comment: Please provide a complete computable MWE.